# IDEA Intellij how to debug PL/SQL code called from Java classes

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, plsql

I am using IDEA Intellij v11, Java and PL/SQL packages. At the moment, in Intellij I am able to debut Java and PL/SQL separately which is fine but it is not really what I would like to do. I would like to be able to debug PL/SQL packages that are called from my Java application. This is to complete all cycle. I would like to add breakpoints in Java and also in PL/SQL and when executing my Intranet, to be able to debug everything, Java and PL/SQL called from Java so I can see exactly the parameters that my PL/SQL procedures are receiving from Java, etc. Is that possible ? anyone knows how ? any plug-in that allow me to do this ? At the moment I am trying DB Navigator but I am able to debug PL/SQL directly not from Java calls. Thanks, Felix.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to debug between java code and PL/SQL... is there a reason why you can't just debug the responses / results you get back in the java context after the stored procedure returns the result?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, more than debug responses/results in Java, I want to debug PL/SQL procedures with parameters I am receiving from Java without any manual action. I mean, total real debugging and not separately. Anyway, I already found an answer to my question and it is working fine !! Here for instance: http://sueharper.blogspot.ie/2006/07/remote-debugging-with-sql-developer_13.html

Comment: That looks really interesting, Ill read the blog post tomorrow - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Debugging two different technologies at the same time is difficult but doable. As you are saying that you can debug both of them separately right. 
I would suggest is to debug both of them using separate tools instead of trying to find a tool which can debug both. 
If it can't be done, then run all your SQL statements side by side and compare the results to the result set in JAVA.

**INFO:**
Also if you are using proper configuration all the error thrown by SQL are returned to JAVA.